# What is the index field direction for $gt, $lt, $gte, $lte?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Consider this aggregate query in MongoDB:

```
"match": {
    "$expr": {
        "$and": [{
            "$ne": ["$bool", true]
        }, {
            "$gt": ["$date", {
                "$dateFromString": {
                    "dateString": aDate
                }
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

The `date` field value is for example:

```
date: {
  "$date": "2018-09-25T15:28:37.743Z"
}
```

Is the correct index `{ date: -1, bool: 1 }` or `{ date: 1, bool: 1 }` considering the date constraint is `$gt` and not `$lt`?

Comment: I don't think it would matter, it might sometimes help to sort the index ASC/DESC depending on if you have a high/low date value but that's even questionable

Comment: I'm not sure if the 'date' portion of the index would even be used, considering that there is a conversion taking place between the value of the field and the filter criteria. Running the aggregation with `explain: true` should show if it does. I agree with Sammaye that the asc / desc wouldn't matter here, but the better index might be just `{ bool: 1 }`

Comment: @AdamHarrison I think you are right, the `IXSCAN` is always over all docs. The index actually has a `partialFilterExpression` which I suppressed to keep the question simple. So the query is using the index, but scanning over all docs in the index, so it really seems to ignore the `date: -1`.

Comment: @AdamHarrison I added a date field value example to the question. Is there a way to use `$gt` without the conversion? The `aDate` value in the query is actually a Javascript `Date` object, so maybe there is no conversion necessary after all?

Comment: Hmm, a date index should translate to a millisecond integer field in MongoDB (last I checked which was a year or so ago) but it should be able to use an index on that field, would seem crazy that you cannot index date values, seems totally illogical

Comment: @Sammaye I am using other indices on a date field of the same syntax and they work fine. I think the issue of `IXSCAN` over all docs is another issue related to the aggregate query.

Comment: It could be the boolean value tbh, it is normally considered pointless to add booleans to indexes, it's been a while since I used MongoDB so I am not certain

Comment: @Manuel, does your query include a match that lets mongo know that it can use that index? If you don't have a query portion that is a subset of the partial filter expression, it won't use the date index. (Also, order of -1/1 doesn't matter because you're not sorting in opposing directions, and it's generally better to put boolean indexes _before_ date indexes because when you have millisecond precision on the dates it means that the boolean part doesn't really narrow down which docs you're looking at)

Comment: To be clear, the reason why booleans are normally considered useless is because they only have two values, as such to filter out one values takes the whole index scan of the other value which in many DB systems is not much of a shortcut at all and requires more processing etc etc than just filtering the last boolean docs after you have all the other conditions met, but this is always dependent on scenario of course

Comment: @willis The issue (unrelated to this SO question) of the aggregate query was that for some reason the index was not used with the `$expr` operator. After  "converting" the query and removing the `$expr` the index was used. Maybe a MongoDB bug. Anyway, the question remains whether sort order is important for a date field in an index. Imagine 5 million docs distributed evenly over 5 years time and the query filters only docs from the last week. If the indexed date is ASC (1), does the cursor jump equally fast down >4 years or it is better to have the date DESC (-1) and jump only 1 week?

Comment: Mongo can traverse the index in either direction, so whether you specify -1/1 doesn't matter. It should only matter in cases where you're sorting by more than 1 field at the same time -- the compound index docs have some good deets. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/

Comment: @willis My question is regarding compound indices. Which in direction should the date field be indexed when using `$gte` or does it matter at all?

Comment: It shouldn't matter at all in your situation -- you're not sorting your result set (and you have millisecond precision on your dates so the boolean index is essentially unsorted unless you have multiple events happening every millisecond).

Comment: Let's assume we also sort by `date` and have other fields in the compound index. It is a rather general question, not bound to the specific example above.